# Enqueue requests in a selected endpoint depending on the tenant

Tags: concurrency, architecture

I have the following scenario:

In a multi-tenancy system, I have an endpoint that increases/decreases the amount in an account (unique per tenant). To avoid problems related to concurrency, I would like to know if there is a way to enqueue requests from an endpoint based on the tenant (this value is provided in the headers).

I haven't selected any technology to implement, so I'm open to suggestions.

(I acknowledge that this may not be the best way to address concurrency problems in my application, but I would like to know if this is possible)

I have been researching how to solve this problem using an API gateway (such as Kong) or a message broker

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.